# Changing a function input in the function itself

Tags: python, function

I have a function called `findCand` which takes as an input: `location` and `range`.
The aim is to find a charging station candidate for an EV driver on a journey given these inputs: `location` is the current location of the EV, and `range` is the EV's range. I further have a dataframe `dfDist` which has the distance between all possible locations, and a dictionary `candDict` which I use to accumulate kwh bought at each charging station.
`tolerance = 20` indicates that when there are 20 km left on the range, the driver will need to charge.

So the function looks like this:

```
def findCand(loc, pRange):
    tolerance = 20

    if loc == 'a':
        dest = 'Area 1'
        km = pRange - 50

        if km < tolerance:
            station = random.choice(list(dfDist.loc[(dfDist['a'] < 50) & (dfDist.index != 'a')].index))
            candDict[station] = candDict[station] + 0.15*dfDist[loc][station]
        else:
            pRange = km
            loc = 'b'

    if loc == 'b':
        dest = 'Area 2'
        km = pRange - 75.8

        if km < tolerance:
            station = random.choice(list(dfDist.loc[(dfDist['b'] < 50) & (dfDist.index != 'b')].index))
            candDict[station] = candDict[station] + 0.15*dfDist[loc][station]
        else:
            pRange = km
            loc = 'c'
```

So my question is, how can I update `loc` so that the driver will continue his journey? 
For example, he starts at `a`, the function checks if he needs to charge before continuing to `b`, a decision is made whether or not that happens and then he moves on to `c`. This process goes on until he reaches `i` as in `a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i`

I realize this may be hard to follow so if there is anything unclear please let me know and I will explain it better. However, my main question is **how to update a function input in the function itself**.

Comment: do `return loc` at the end ? to use again at the place you call the method ?

Comment: Seems like you could recursively call it every time the driver reaches a new location with the updated amounts

Comment: @G.Anderson I tried calling the function after I changed `loc` for the first time but I got the following error: `name findCand is not defined`

Comment: I assume that's a typo in `if loc = 'b':`, that's not valid syntax.

Comment: As for updating `loc`, you've done that correctly.  You just need to put in a loop so it will re-run the block.

Comment: @MarkRansom thanks for pointing that out, fixed it.

Comment: @MarkRansom where would you place the loop?

Comment: Around the part that needs to be rerun when `loc` changes.